# Why does this function return integer 17 after completing its recursive run?

Tags: c, function, recursion, static-variables

According to me, the function should return 2 as answer, because every time the function is called recursively,the static variable 'r' is re-assigned zero again.
Note: The passed argument in the function is 5.

```
int fun(int n){
static int r=0;
  if(n<=0)return 0;
  else if(n>3){
   r=n;
   return fun(n-2)+2;
}
  else return fun(n-1)+r;
}
```

The function actually returns 17 when 5 is passed to it.

Comment: `static` local variables are only initialized once. That's one of the main points of them.

Comment: *"the static variable 'r' is re-assigned zero again"* No it's not

Comment: So if you want to reassign static variable `r`, you'll need to add an assignment expression to do so.

Comment: Don't confuse `static int r = 0` with an actual *assignment*. It's actually defining the initial value of the variable, nothing more.

Comment: If it helps, you can pretend that the `static int r=0;` declaration is placed outside the function and it will behave the same. Being inside the function only hides the variable from other functions. In both cases, it is only initialized once. (Without the `static` keyword, inside the function `r` would have _automatic_ storage class, and _would_ be initialized every time the function is called.)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
static int r=0;
```

with

```
static int r;
r = 0;
```

Static variables are initialised only **once** before main. You have to explicitly re-initialise it to 0 each time you need to do it.

Comment: Of course, in that case, there is not much point making the variable static. The only effect of the `static` would be to make the function not MT-safe.

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes indeed. It makes little sense to keep the variable marked as static. I didn't want to deviate from the original source too much as the author appeared to be confused on how static variables works.